# PayPal Adaptive Payments PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been recently trying to make an API request using PHP to PayPal to pay multiple accounts but so far I have no luck.

`

```
class PayPal
{
    public $_headers = array();
    public $_config = array();
    public $_data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions()))
        {
            trigger_error("CURL extension is not installed or enabled", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    public function update_headers(array $credentails)
    {
        $this->_headers = $credentails;
        return $this;
    }

    public function update_config(array $config)
    {
        $this->_config = $config;
        return $this;
    }

    public function pay($data, $call)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->get_url());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->_headers);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }

    public function split_pay()
    {
        // create the pay request
        $this->_data = array(
            "actionType" =>"PAY",
            "currencyCode" => "USD",
            "receiverList" => array(
                "receiver" => array(
                    array(
                        "amount"=> "1.00",
                        "email"=>"******@gmail.com"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "amount"=> "2.00",
                        "email"=>"*********.co.uk"
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            "returnUrl" => "http://test.local/payments/confirm",
            "cancelUrl" => "http://test.local/payments/cancel",
            "requestEnvelope" => array(
                "errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                "detailLevel" => "ReturnAll",
            ),
        );

        return $this->pay($this->_data, "PAY");
    }

    private function get_url()
    {
        if (empty($this->_config))
        {
            trigger_error("You have not setup the config", E_USER_ERROR);    
        }

        return $this->_config['url'];
    }

    public function call_headers()
    {
        if (empty($this->_headers))
        {
            trigger_error("You have not set any headers", E_USER_ERROR);    
        }

        print_r($this->_headers);
    }
}
```

?>`

This is a class file which I have created, it is very rough but its not working. Here is some more code.
`load->library('paypal');
$pp = new PayPal();

```
        //Bring me the money!
        //Headers for paypal
        $headers = array(
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ********",
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: *********",
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: **********",
            "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
            "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
            "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T"
        );

        $config = array(
            'url' => 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
            'username' => '********',
            'password' => '********',
            'signature' => '********',
            'app_id' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
        );

        $pp->update_headers($headers)->update_config($config);
        print_r($pp->split_pay());
```

?>
`
I am being returned with this response.
responseEnvelope.timestamp=2014-04-22T06%3A15%3A49.821-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=b3d05fe547e22&responseEnvelope.build=10680030&error(0).errorId=580001&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Invalid+request%3A+%7B0%7D

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be

Comment: According to the [API Error & Warning list](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) your error is `A Parameter is Invalid : Unable to identify parameter`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy This is strange cause I had copy and pasted the details from PayPal Dashboard

Comment: Need to get a look at the full raw request you're sending.  That said, I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make this all much quicker and easier for you.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I fixed the issue, I was requesting the format to be in NV I changed the format to JSON and it has worked straight away.